# How to unregisterReceiver which is used in fragment?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have onReceive method implemented in my FragmentInfo class, because I need to update UI, when intent is send from somewhere else in my code. I register this receiver from Fragment, but from MainActivity, because it must be registered from Activity. I don't know where to place unregisterReceiver call, so my program crashes. I'm getting error:

**MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver FragmentInfo that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?**

I was trying to call unregisterReceiver from MainActivity onPause method, like it is usually done, but from MainActivity I can't accessed mBroadcastReceiver. How can I solve this?

```
public class FragmentInfo extends Fragment {

    //nested class BroadcastReceiver
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        //from there we must update FragmentInfo UI
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //updateFragmentInfo(intent);
            updateUiInfo();
            //unregisterReceiver
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
        }
    };

    private TextView textView3;
    private TextView textView5;
    private TextView textView7;
    private TextView textView8;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        //dynamic register BroadcastReceiver, for triggering intent when BT connection is established
        //BroadcastReceiver can be registered static in ManifestFile
        IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        //register message 
        mIntentFilter.addAction("bluetooth_established_intent");
        //we must call registerReceiver from MainActivity!
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).registerReceiver(this.mBroadcastReceiver,mIntentFilter);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: I unregister receiver after call updateUIInfo and it works now. I edit in code.**

Comment: use unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver) ? You can do it in onDestroy()

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to register broadcast receiver in onResume and unregister in onPause. So that every time the fragment becomes visible to the user it registers receiver and every time it becomes invisible (removed or replaced with another fragment) it unregisters receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `unregisterReceiver` from the following method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finally resolve the leak this way:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(YOUR_RECEIVER_HERE);
```

Because by doing

```
getActivity().unregisterReceiver(...)
```

or

```
getContext().unregisterReceiver(...)
```

in both `onPause()` and `onStop()` did not help.

Comment: where did you put LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(YOUR_RECEIVER_HERE); in your fragment ?

Comment: Since its the unregister part, probably in onPause()... was some time ago, cant recall correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You will call `unregisterReceiver` from `onPause` method in your Fragment.

Comment: -1 because this is wrong. once your fragment get `onPause()` then receiver is gone and never re-registed.

Comment: I can't because receiver is not registered yet, so program crashes. I found solution, and it seems that it works. I unregistered it in onReceive method, after call updateUIInfo.

Comment: You can set a boolean variable about whether it is registered or not. And you can use like if(is_registered) getActivity.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);